# Hyperledger fabric - Migrate a channel from one network to another network.

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Suppose I 'm running a two fabric networks for my Org, which is hosting few different channels.

Network A is having channel 1, 2 and 3.
Network B is having channel 4, 5 and 6.

Now say channel 3 has many transactions and it's growing at an exponential rate so I decided to separate that channel on a different network. 
Can I possibly move channel 3 to Network B? Or maybe Network C as well which is a fresh n/w.

The possible options are. 
 1. Replay all the transactions on Network B/C. Somehow I need to capture all the transactions happened on channel C and then replay it. Timestamp of the transactions here would change for sure. 
 2. Copy files from Network A and Create Network C which is exact copy of Network A and then find a way to delete data from Channel 1 and 2. Not sure if this is a clean way. 
 3. Join Network A from Network C as an separate Org in Channel 3 so, all the transactions would sync from network A to network C and then I somehow remove Channel 3 from network A. Not sure if this would work. I wish leaving channel was an option provided. 
 4. I already tried migrating kafka topics/Couchdb data to separate instances and carry on from there, but failed.

None of the options I mentioned might work so If any one has a better idea please share.